# Determine whether the function is pointwise and uniform convergent

Tags: analysis

Given the function $\left( \operatorname{sgn}\left(\cos\dfrac{x}{n}\right) \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  where
$$
\operatorname{sgn}(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $x >0$} \\
0, & \text {if $x=0$} \\
-1, & \text{if $x< 0$}
\end{cases} 
$$

First I need to determine whether this is pointwise convergent which I know involves finding the limit but do I do this for each separate case?

If it is pointwise convergent to a limit function, how do I use this to determine whether it is uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find the limit for an arbitrary $x$. For each $x$ the limit of $\frac{x}{n}$ will go towards $0$ and so the function will go towards $sign(\cos (0))=sign(1)=1$. So this converges pointwise to $f(x)=1$.

Now for uniform convergence, note that by the definition we need to produce an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ for any $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $n\geq N$ and $x$ in the domain, we have that :

$|sign(\cos(\frac{x}{n})-1|<\epsilon$.

We know that cosine is periodic and varies between values of $1$ and $-1$, and so the value of $sign(\cos)$ will also vary depending on the value of $x$ chosen. So what you want to do is find an $x$ value that will mess this inequality up for any $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos$ is positive in a neighbourhood of $0$ (i.e. $U = (- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is $n$ with $\frac{x}{n} \in U$. For $m \geq n$ we thus have
$$\operatorname(\cos(\frac{x}{m})) = 1.$$
Now to show that it is not uniformly convergent, observe that the chosen $n$ in the argumentation above depends on $x$. This is used to show that the sequence is not uniformly convergent.